# Faster returns comparisons in Pandas dataframes?

Tags: pandas, performance, dataframe

I have DataFrame containing 600,000 pairs of IDs. Each ID has returns Data in a large monthly returns_df. For each of the 600K pairs, I do the following

1. I set left and right DataFrames equal to their subset of returns_df.
2. I merge DataFrames to get months they both have data
3. I compute an absolute distance by comparing each, then summing results, and running a sigmoid function.

This process is taking ~12 hours as my computer has to create subsets of returns_df each time to compare. Can I substantially speed this up through some sort of vectorized solution or faster filtering?

```
def get_return_similarity(row):
    left = returns_df[returns_df['FundID']==row.left_side_id]
    right = returns_df[returns_df['FundID']==row.right_side_id]
    temp = pd.merge(left,right, how='inner', on=['Year','Month'])
    if temp.shape[0]<12: # Return if overlap < 12 months
        return 0
    temp['diff'] = abs(temp['Return_x'] - temp['Return_y'])
    return 1/(math.exp(70*temp['diff'].sum()/(temp['diff'].shape[0]))) #scaled sigmoid function

df['return_score'] = df[['left_side_id','right_side_id']].apply(get_return_similarity,axis=1)
```

Thanks in advance for your help! Trying to get better with Pandas

Edit: As suggested, the basic data format is below
returns_df
[image: returns_df]

df I am running the apply on:

[image: df I am doing the apply on]

Comment: it will be wise to provide a minimal df data.

Comment: working on it. It looked good in the preview but isn't coming out here....

Comment: Didn't work, even when explicitly using a markdown tool for tables. Uploaded as images. Thanks!